# How to create a menu bar in vaadin 10

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin10

I am a beginner of vaadin 10 and I am going to create a menu bar. I am not sure what components to be used to make it exactly look like a sidebar and simple menu options vertically.

I can create this using buttons and navigations but not sure what the best way is.

P.S. I am a backend java developer, not a front-end guy, it's highly appreciable if you can explain it as simply as possible.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0):

MenuBar component has been removed from v10 :-(
https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components.html

Comment: Is there any demo or code sample available for this?

Comment: **Update:** A `MenuBar` widget is planned for development by Vaadin Ltd, scheduled for Vaadin 14 release. [See the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components.html). On GitHub, see Issue # 4694 [*MenuBar component*](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4694)